# Is there a way to tell if a BroadcastReceiver is being called for a result rather than the initial broadcast?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Assume an Android application which implements a `BroadcastReceiver`.

The `BroadastReceiver` is registered at runtime (using `Context#registerReceiver()`) to pick up some broadcast Intents.

Somewhere else in the code the application calls `sendOrderedBroadcast()` to send a broadcast intent to another application, with the same `BroadcastReceiver` passed as the `resultReceiver` argument. That is, when the recipient has processed the broadcast and (optionally) set a result, it is returned to our `BroadcastReceiver`.

Without resorting to hacks such as “marking” intents the app has sent itself, or distinguishing based on the Intent action, is there a universal way for the `BroadcastReceiver` to tell that it is currently processing the result of an Intent initiated by its own app, rather than a broadcast initiated by another app?

Comment: Cant you just add your own keys to the bundle being passed.

Comment: That’s what I meant by “marking” intents sent by the app—and it might come with unwanted side effects. I’d like to know if Android provides a universal way to figure that out without using such hacks.

Comment: If its not related to system broadcast you can resort to LocalBroadcast

Comment: Sender and recipient of the broadcast are two different apps, I’ve edited the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for but you could look into BroadCastReceiver Permissions.